# Library class as return type for methods in aidl interface

Tags: android, ipc, android-library, aidl

In IPC to interpret data received the process should be knowing the Class structure. So i made a Library of all required classes which are all implementing Parcelable.

1. In library i have defined aidl files for all calsses and ensured that these file are present in JAR.
2. In application, i have created same aidl file and place in the same package name as in library.

In aidl file which contains method definitions no error is shown but in code section of Stub() i get that the Library class as return could not be found.

if i create the same library object inside the method it shows valid object, but something with it as return type.

so, i moved one of the class from library to application there is problem with this class.
What have i missed so that library classes are not recognized as return type.

Note: i edited the compiler created class file for aidl in gen folder and added import to my library, error is solved but i cant save it, compiler will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

what a shame... Package name of classes in my library had first letter as capital while i messed it by creating package structure in my application with small letter...

Wont delete the Question. someone else might also do same mistake